# How to show the number of installed packages

Tags: debian, package-management

What is the Debian equivalent of Fedora's `yum list installed | grep wc --lines`?

Answer (score 13):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=485131):

To list installed packages:

```
dpkg --list | wc --lines
```

To see if a package is installed:

```
dpkg --list | grep package
```

Comment: You're including the header lines and some non-installed packages (e.g. `rc` (uninstalled but with config files left over)) in your count.

Answer (score 12):

```
dpkg -l | grep -c '^ii'
```

There are subtle variants like `dpkg -l | grep -c '^?i'` if you want to include packages that are installed but whose removal you've requested. Another way is

```
aptitude search '~i' |wc -l
```

You can even poke directly into the dpkg database:

```
sh -c 'set /var/lib/dpkg/info/*; echo $#'
```

This one includes packages that are not installed but that have configuration files left over; you can list these with `dpkg -l | grep '^rc'`.

Answer (score 2):

What I've been using is:

```
dpkg --get-selections | wc --lines
```

This will give you the number of installed packages.

If you want to find if a particular package is installed, use:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep <package>
```

I believe that this will solve [Gilles' complaint about including other, non-installed packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8053).

Answer (score 2):

apt list --installed | grep -c 'installed'

#apt list --installed=> shows all packages> we grep the results from the list only for the lines containing the string "installed"

For me, this command worked

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -l` is nice but I actually find myself using **`apt-show-versions`** (not installed by default on Debian; install the package of the same name) a lot instead, especially when I want to process the output further (dpkg tries to be too clever with line wrapping).

Answer (score 1):

[Synaptic](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/synaptic), a GUI package manager, displays the count at the bottom of its main window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want an exact count of packages, you should not count the header lines output by `dpkg-query -l`, so you need a pattern to match lines starting with `ii`. The following one-liner gives you the number of lines starting with `ii` and therefore the number of installed packages:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep "^ii" | wc -l
```

This gives the same output as

```
 dpkg --get-selections | grep "[[:space:]]install" | wc -l
```

The grep pattern in the second command ignores lines that contain the string "deinstall" in the output of `dpkg --get-selections`.

Answer (score -1):

For instace, you can do this:

```
dpkg-query -l | nl | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: OK, it's true that `nl | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'` will report the number of lines in its input (except, if there is no input, it will say nothing instead of reporting `0`) — but why would you recommend such a kludge when other answers are already using `wc -l`?

Comment: That's funny cause i didn't read previous answers! @G-Man ...but this still remains a good answer.