# What does "^ii" mean in the command grep -c "^ii"

Tags: linux, grep

**Description**

To find the number of packages installed on the system, I tried the command `dpkg -l | grep -c "^ii"` (found here: [How to show the number of installed packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8045)).

**Questions**

1. It works, but I don't understand what `"^ii"` exactly is.
2. After trying another command, `apt list --installed | grep -c "installed"`, I got 738 as the response, which is incorrect. The correct answer is 737. What's the added one?

Comment: For the second question, you'd have to compare the output, maybe try `diff <(apt list --installed | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | sort) <(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | sort) --side-by-side`

Comment: "^ii" is a regular expression (regex). And can be analyzed and explained by many tools: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @Sandburg Note that `grep` uses POSIX basic regular expressions by default (or extended ones with `-E`) but that the site you link to does not support any type of POSIX expressions. So don't be surprised if you test stuff there that then does not work with `grep`.

Comment: I have reopened the question because, IMHO, asking about what `^ii` means is not the same as asking about what `ii` means at the start of the output from `dpkg -l`.

Comment: re. `apt list --installed`, if you mean it gives one more hit than `dpkg -l | grep -c "^ii"` see if the output has something that's obviously a false positive, like a header line, or even a packet name that matches "installed". Or how do you know the count is wrong? Either that, or look for packets in the output of `dpkg` that are not in state `ii` (and not `rc`, which would be usual for removed packages). I'm not sure what the corresponding output from `apt` would be in each case, but you might have some pkg in a "broken" state. Try e.g. `dpkg -l | grep -e ^i -e ^.i | grep -v ^ii`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `^ii` is a regular expression that, when used with `grep`, will cause `grep` to output only lines that start with the two characters `ii`.  The initial `^` is an "anchor" that will force the expression to either match at the start of a line or not at all.  Without the `^`, `grep` would have listed lines that contain `ii` anywhere. With `-c`, `grep` outputs the number of matching lines.

As for what `ii` mean at the start of the line in the output from `dpkg -l`, see [What does "ii" in the first colums of the output of dpkg-query mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459296)

As for your second query, since you don't say why you think the number is incorrect, it's impossible to answer.